# R: grep, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: r

I want to get all the positions of "_" in my string:

```
MyString <- "Test_Test_Test"

grep("_", MyString)
```

This returns however:

```
[1] 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Use `gregexpr` rather than `grep`

```
 MyString<-"Test_Test_Test"
> gregexpr('_', MyString)
[[1]]
[1]  5 10
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Hadley's `stringr` package:

```
library("stringr")

MyString <- "Test_Test_Test"
str_locate_all(MyString, "_")
# [[1]]
#  start end
# [1,]     5   5
# [2,]    10  10
```